# macro for glossaries counter

Tags: macros, glossaries, counters

I want custom my glossaries, and specially I want to have something like

My glossary entry, its signification (see p. 1),  if this entry mentioned only once

or

My glossary entry, its signification (see pp. 1,2),  if this entry mentioned several times

So I create command to count the number of item in the list ##2 used by

```
\newglossarystyle
```

and another command to print `see p.` or `see pp.`

I tested these command outside of the `\newglossarystyle` definition, it seems to work. But inside this definition the command to count the number of item in the list don't accept the `##2` argument.

Here is my example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[onecolumn,twoside,openright,a4paper,11pt]{report}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        

\usepackage{hyperref}       
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pgffor}     % you don't need this if tikz is already included

\usepackage[toc,acronym,xindy,section=section]{glossaries} 



\newcounter{moncompteur}

\newcommand{\Znumlist}[1]{
\setcounter{moncompteur}{0}
    \foreach \e in{#1}{%
    \addtocounter{moncompteur}{1}
    }
\themoncompteur
}

\newcommand{\montest}[1]{%
    \ifnum#1<2%
        \seename\ p.
    \else%
        \seename\ pp.
    \fi%
}
\newglossarystyle{mylist}{  %
    \setglossarystyle{list} % base this style on the list style
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
    %\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space \Znumlist{##2}\montest{\themoncompteur}\space ##2} %
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space \Znumlist{##2}\space ##2}
}


\newglossary[ntg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Glossaire}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Nomenclature}

 \makeglossaries        %




\newglossaryentry{glscard}{ %type=main,
    name=cardinality,
    description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

\newglossaryentry{mesh}{type=notation,
    name={Mesh},
    description={maillage},
    sort={m}}

\newglossaryentry{mbb}{type=symbols,    
    name={\ensuremath{ {M} }},
    text={ {M} },                                 
    description={matrix},               
    sort=m,                             
    see=[see also]{glscard}} 

\begin{document}       % 

\setglossarystyle{mylist}    
\printglossary[toctitle=Lexique,type=main]
\newacronym{pc}{PC}{personal computer}   
\printglossary[toctitle=Acronyms,type=acronym]
\printglossary[type=notation]
\printglossary[type=symbols]

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{ab}

 \gls{pc}; \gls{glscard}; \gls{mbb}; \gls{mesh}; \newpage 
 \gls{mesh}

\Znumlist{1,3,4} \montest{\themoncompteur}

\end{document}
```

How do I use a argument like `##2` inside a command?

Comment: Why 2 `#`s rather than 1?

Comment: Maybe it's worth noticing that `##2` inside the ``renewcommand`` inside the ``newglossarystyle`` is passed on as one single item instead of a list of items, in a manner of speaking. (``[a],[b],[c]`` becomes ``[a,b,c]``)

Comment: @PierreSchroeder : I tried to know what is the input of the `\Znumlist` by adding `\themoncompteur` in my command (as you can see in my example). It prints the input list in the document part (`\Znumlist{1,3,4}` in my example) but it prints a blank in the glossaries. This is why I think that the input `##2` is not recognized. 

@cfr : `##2{ is the list of the pages where the glossaries commands are used and `##1` is the signification of the glossary entry. This is why I use `##2` rather than `##1`, I'm interested by the list of pages not by the signification.

Comment: @Romain I think you misunderstood my comment. :) I totally get what you're trying to do and I don't know the solution to the problem. BUT: while twiddling with your example I found out that the counter ``\themoncompteur`` is always 1 inside the definition for the ``newglossarystyle``, because inside the ``newglossarystyle``, ``##2`` is passed on as one single item ``"1, 2, 3"`` and not as a list of items ``''1'', ''2'', ''3''`` as it should be passed on. I don't know why, but if somebody else seeing this quesiton knows how to solve THAT, your problem is actually solved!

Comment: @Romain Does [the answer to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126891/how-to-add-the-word-page-or-pages-in-the-glossary) help? It does not answer how to make your macros work, but it should do what you want to achieve with them.

Comment: @PierreSchroeder Thanks for your precisions about the previous comment. You're right! About the answer linked it's almost does the job. There is some problems with this solution : it does not work with xindy and it does not keep the hyperref link on the pages. But it's a good clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `glossaries` package already provides a mechanism for counting the number of times an entry has been used, but it must be enabled using `\glsenableentrycount`. This was added to version 4.14 and is documented in [section 14.1](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:enableentrycount) of the user manual.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\glsenableentrycount

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\newacronym{ab}{AB}{sample abbreviation}

\begin{document}
Number of times ``sample'' was used on the last run:
\glsentryprevcount{sample}.

\gls{sample}. \gls{sample}. \gls{ab}.

Number of times ``sample'' has been used in this run \emph{so far}:
\glsentrycurrcount{sample}.

\newpage

\gls{sample}. \gls{ab}.

\newpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces (after a second run):

[image: Image of result. Used 3 times on previous run and 2 times so far]

Notes:

1. `\glsenableentrycount` must be used before you define your entries.
2. This mechanism imposes a preamble-only restriction on the use of `\newglossaryentry` (and, therefore, also `\newacronym` which internally uses `\newglossaryentry`).

You can then use `\glsentryprevcount` in your glossary style:

```
\newglossarystyle{mylist}
{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
          \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
       \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space
       \ifnum\glsentryprevcount{##1}>1 pp.\else p.\fi\ ##2}%
}
```

Take care as the previous count value represents the total number of times the entry has been used. This value is reset back to zero with `\glsreset` and it also doesn't necessarily match the number of locations in the location list. For example, if an entry is used twice on one page but nowhere else in the document, then the location list will have a single location (that page) but the entry count will be 2.

The (currently experimental) [glossaries-extra](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/expl/) package enhances this feature and provides per-unit counting.

**Edit:**

Just using `glossaries`:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}       

\usepackage[toc,acronym,xindy,section=section]{glossaries} 

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
  \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
  \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space
  \ifnum\glsentryprevcount{##1}>1 pp.\else p.\fi\ ##2}%
}


\newglossary[ntg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Glossaire}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Nomenclature}

\makeglossaries        %

\glsenableentrycount

\newglossaryentry{glscard}{
    name=cardinality,
    description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

\newglossaryentry{mesh}{type=notation,
    name={Mesh},
    description={maillage},
    sort={m}}

\newglossaryentry{mbb}{type=symbols,    
    name={\ensuremath{M}},
    text={M},                                 
    description={matrix},               
    sort=m,                             
    see=[see also]{glscard}} 

\newacronym{pc}{PC}{personal computer}   

\setglossarystyle{mylist}    

\begin{document} 
\printglossary[toctitle=Lexique,type=main]
\printglossary[toctitle=Acronyms,type=acronym]
\printglossary[type=notation]
\printglossary[type=symbols]

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{ab}

\gls{pc}; \gls{pc}; \gls{glscard}; \gls{mbb}; \gls{mesh}; \newpage 
\gls{mesh}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of glossaries]

This mostly works except for the `pc` entry which occurs twice on page 2 but not on any other page. Since the total usage for that entry is greater than 1, `pp` is used instead of `p` even though there's only a single page in the location list. Below is an alternative solution that uses `glossaries-extra`.

**Caveat:** `glossaries-extra` is still experimental and this may fail in the odd occasions where entries occur in a page-break spanning paragraph due to TeX's asynchronous output routine.

The following adapts your mwe to use `glossaries-extra`:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}       
\usepackage[nopostdot=false,% put a dot after the descriptions
 abbreviations,% create a separate list of abbreviations
 xindy,section=section]{glossaries-extra} 

\GlsXtrEnableEntryUnitCounting
 {general,abbreviation}% apply to both general and abbreviation categories
 {0}% don't trigger index suppression
 {page}% count per page

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
  \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
  \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space
  \ifnum\glsentryprevtotalcount{##1}>1 pp.\else p.\fi\ ##2}%
}

% In case an entry is used two or more times on one page but not on any of the
% other pages.
\let\ORGglsxtrpostunset\glsxtrpostunset

\renewcommand*{\glsxtrpostunset}[1]{%
  \ifnum\glsentrycurrcount{#1}>0 \else\ORGglsxtrpostunset{#1}\fi
}


\newglossary[ntg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Glossaire}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Nomenclature}

\makeglossaries

% general entries

\newglossaryentry{glscard}{
    name=cardinality,
    description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

\newglossaryentry{mesh}{type=notation,
    name={Mesh},
    description={maillage},
    sort={m}}

\newglossaryentry{mbb}{type=symbols,    
    name={\ensuremath{M}},
    text={M},                                 
    description={matrix},               
    sort=m,                             
    see=[see also]{glscard}} 

% abbreviations

\newabbreviation{pc}{PC}{personal computer}   

\setglossarystyle{mylist}    

\begin{document} 

\printglossary[toctitle=Lexique,type=main]
\printabbreviations
\printglossary[type=notation]
\printglossary[type=symbols]

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{ab}

 \gls{pc}; \gls{pc}; \gls{glscard}; \gls{mbb}; \gls{mesh}; \newpage 
 \gls{mesh}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of glossaries]

Notes:

- Although the `glossaries-extra` package internally loads the `glossaries` package, it sets different defaults (e.g. `toc` and `nopostdot`). To illustrate this I've removed the `toc` option and added `nopostdot` to emulate the settings of your mwe.
- The `glossaries-extra` package has a different (and better) way of dealing with abbreviations.
- With the *per unit* counting, `\glsentrycurrcount` and `\glsentryprevcount` refer to the count for the *current unit*. So if you have, say, `\glsentryprevcount{pc}` on page 1, you'll get the number of times the entry was used *on page 1* (where the unit counter is `page`). This means that it's of no use in the glossary style, since you're not interested in how many times the entry has been used in the glossary (which happens to be 0).
- The *total* count (from the previous run) is obtained with `\glsentryprevtotalcount` so the style tests if this value is greater than one.
- To cater for the possibility of an entry being used two or more times on one page of the document but not used at all on any other page, I've adjusted the definition of `\glsxtrpostunset`. For example, I've used `pc` twice on one page but nowhere else, which would've set the total count to 2, and "pp" would've appeared in the glossary for the `pc` entry (as in the previous example). This modification effectively sets a maximum count of 1 per page.

Comment: Your solution with `\glsenableentrycount` is interesting ! But, my problem was more focused on the number of page where the entry appears. So, there is no existence of a counter for the number of page where the entry appears? Or maybe in the future ? Otherwise it would solve simply this problem.

I will check `glossaries-extra`and validate your solution if I found the solution in this package.

Comment: I had `\usepackage{glossaries-extar}` and `\GlsXtrEnableEntryUnitCounting{general}{0}{page}` to your solution using `\glsenableentrycount` and `\glsentryprevcount`. This in order prevent from the problems you mentioned. But there no change on the result. So what should be the correct syntax about this configuration?

Comment: @Romain I've edited my answer.

Comment: I validated your solution. Since you edited it is very clear. I just don't understand what does the command `\renewcommand*{\glsxtrpostunset}`. But I checked with several case and it works fine. 
The possibilities of `glossaries-extra` will be added to `glossaries` or `glossaries-extra` will become a new CTAN package supported by TeXLive?

Comment: @Romain glossaries-extra is now [on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) as a separate package. It should be available on both TeX Live and MikTeX. (`\glsxtrpostunset` is an extra command provided by `glossaries-extra`, which modifies the behaviour of `\glsunset` and similar commands. It's redefined by the entry counting commands. I've just made a slight modification to it in my example.)

Comment: It's good think about this package.
By the way, in order to have a good behaviour of your solution I have to compile with the following sequence : pdflatex, makeglossaries, pdflatex, makeglossaries, pdflatex, makeglossaries, pdflatex. Is it normal ? or perhaps you should add it to your solution.