# modify the design shown in the output of glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I need help with the following.

In the list of words that I generate with the glossaries package, I want to add the legend (see page x), the parentheses are also part of what I want.

The expression p. or pages. corresponds to whether a single entry or multiple entries are shown.

Image 1 and 2 summarize my ideas.

[image]

[image]

Thank you

I add the code that generates this output

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage{ImagoMundi}% my style  
\usepackage{bib-valbusa}% my style  
\addbibresource{MANGIANTINI.bib}  

%% SIGLAS  
\usepackage[toc,style=index]{glossaries}  
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}  
\makeglossaries  
\newglossaryentry{AOMA}{name={AOMA:},text={AOMA},description={Asociación Obrera Minera Argentina}}  
\newglossaryentry{APR}{name={APR:},text={APR},description={Alianza Popular Revolucionaria}}  

...  

\begin{document}  
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Índice de siglas}}  

\gls{AOMA}  

\gls{APR}  

...  

\printglossary  

...  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show the minimal compilable document that generates this output, i.e. include the acronym or glossary definitions as well.

Comment: 'code'\usepackage[toc,style=index]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{AOMA}{name={AOMA:},text={AOMA},description={Asociación Obrera Minera Argentina}}
\newglossaryentry{APR}{name={APR:},text={APR},description={Alianza Popular Revolucionaria}}
\newglossaryentry{UFA}{name={UFA:},text={UFA},description={Unión Feminista Argentina}}

Comment: No, add this to your post, not as a comment -- and it is not compilable at all

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299646

Comment: I recommend you move your solution to the answer area below. You can then mark it as solved (with the tick button), which will move the question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Nicola Talbot, a small modification to method 1 that you suggested, reached to achieve my goal, this is the resulting code.

```
%%GLOSARIO  
\usepackage[toc,style=mylong,nopostdot]{glossaries}  
\glsnoexpandfields  
\glsenableentrycount  

% Código que modifica la salida del glosario  
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%  
  \setglossarystyle{long}%  
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%  
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 1.5cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.85\hsize}}}  
     {\end{longtable}}%  
      \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%  
      \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &  
      \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space  
      \ifnum\glsentryprevcount{##1}=1\relax  
        (v\'ease p\'ag.   
      \else  
        (v\'ease p\'ags.   
      \fi  
      ##2).\tabularnewline  
     }%  
 }
```

And this is the resulting image

[image]