# How to make the term "page" show in the Glossary list?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, cross-referencing, page-numbering, glossaries

I have recently started to use the package `glossaries`.

When I make the Glossary list, the page numbers show up at the end of the description. So far so good.

I have found information about how to not show the page numbers.

I have found one solution in [How to add the word "page" or "pages" in the Glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126891/how-to-add-the-word-page-or-pages-in-the-glossary#) how to **add the words "page" or "pages"**. But it had some issues:

1. The previously existing cross-references disappeared. It used to look like

   [image: How it previously looked].

   So my question is, can you include the words "page" or "pages" without losing the clickable cross-references?
2. Another problem with the found solution is that it tends to repeat the term "page"

   [image: Screenshot example]

   instead of just using it once.

**The second issue** seems to be solved

[image: The term "page" only appears once per entry]

in the proposed solution of [Problem with inserting "page" in Glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299646/problem-with-inserting-page-in-glossary), but I was not sure how to implement the proposed solution. At least I got error codes when trying to add the

```
% Columns in acronym table
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
      \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
      \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
      \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space 
      \pagesfalse
      \usepagestag{##1}\space
      ##2%
      \ifpages
        \savepagestag{##1}{pages}%
      \else
        \savepagestag{##1}{page}%
      \fi
      \tabularnewline
     }%
 }
```

code block from [Problem with inserting "page" in Glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299646/problem-with-inserting-page-in-glossary) to my `.tex` document.

Can anyone help me out with this?

/Lars

Comment: Please do never post screenshots of code, but real code.

Comment: It is NOT. Please read our guidelines. It looks good.

Comment: It did not look good, but probably someone fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method is to use the extension package `glossaries-extra` which provides `\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[postdot]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{Page: }{Pages: }

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample1},description={first example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={sample2},description={second example}}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample1}, \gls{sample2}.

\newpage

\gls{sample2}.

\newpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

The build process is `latex`, `makeglossaries`, `latex`, `latex` (replace `latex` with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex` as appropriate).