# Glossarysstyle "altlist" look using package "glossaries-extra" instead of "glossaries"

Tags: glossaries

In a previously asked question [How to make the term "page" show in the Glossary list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365680/how-to-make-the-term-page-show-in-the-glossary-list/365689#365689), I was advised to use the `glossaries-extra` package instead of the `glossaries` package.

In the `glossaries` package I used `\setglossarystyle{altlist}` in order to make my list contain:

1. the abbreviation
2. what the abbreviations stands for
3. a description of the abbreviation

It can look like:

[image]

when using the acronym entry

```
\newacronym
[description = {Immediate instability point: sometimes used in the literature as a synonym to SLL}]
{iip}{IIP}{Immediate instability point}
```

but after starting to use the `glossaries-extra` package it looks like this instead:

[image]

Why is that, and what can be done about it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `glossaries-extra` package uses a different abbreviation mechanism to the base `glossaries` package, which allows greater flexibility and multiple abbreviation styles. Abbreviations are defined using `\newabbreviation` but to allow for easy conversion from the base `glossaries`, `\newacronym` is redefined in terms of `\newabbreviation`. The style for abbreviations defined using `\newacronym` should now be set using `\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{`*style-name*`}`. For example:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-desc}
\newacronym
[description = {Immediate instability point: sometimes used in the literature as a synonym to SLL}]
{iip}{IIP}{Immediate instability point}
```