# Change format of glossaries number list

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I would like to change the format used to print the number list in a glossary created with the `glossaries` package to match the style that I am using in my bibliography. However, I cannot find any information how to achieve this.

Starting from the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nopostdot,style=indexgroup,nolist]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{target}
{
    name={target},
    description={Foo foo bar}
}
\newglossaryentry{link}
{
    name={link},
    description={Another example \gls{target}}
}

\begin{document}

\Gls{target} and \gls{link}.

\newpage

\printnoidxglossary

\end{document}
```

I would like to achieve a style that resembles my bibliography which looks like:

[image]

That means I want to have "used on: p. 42" or "used on: pp. 3, 10, 17-30" in italics.

Comment: What exactly is the 'style' that you are trying to replicate? I'm afraid I'm not quite sure how to extrapolate from your (bibliography) example to what you are expecting your glossary to look like. Your glossary entries will have DOI? You want the page links to be in `used on: pp ...`? etc.

Comment: @Troy I have updated to the question to be clear on this. It is the "used on:..." part that I want to have.

Comment: The [`noidx` option](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option1) doesn't form ranges. You'll have to switch to using `\makeglossaries` with `makeindex` or `xindy` and try [How to make the term “page” show in the Glossary list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365680)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot that is what I do in my production use case. However, I don't even know how to change the text before the list to include "used on:".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a couple of minor modifications to the example from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365689/19862). Just replace

```
 \GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{Page: }{Pages: }
```

with

```
\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{\textit{used on p.~}}{\textit{used on pp.~}}
```

for the number list prefix, and for the italic number list use

```
\renewcommand{\GlsXtrFormatLocationList}{\textit}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{\textit{used on p.~}}{\textit{used on pp.~}}
\renewcommand{\GlsXtrFormatLocationList}{\textit}

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample1},description={first
example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={sample2},description={second
example}}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample1}, \gls{sample2}.

\newpage

\gls{sample2}.

\newpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

Comment: Thank you! Would have been easy if I found the other answer while searching.

Comment: For acronyms, is it possible to add a dot after long version automatically? For normal glossaries entries I always use a complete sentence, but for acronyms a dot would be needed before the "used on".

Comment: @languitar The `postdot` package option will automatically add a dot after all the descriptions. If you only want it done after certain entries you can use the post-description hook. For example, if you define acronyms using `\newacronym`, this automatically sets `category=acronym`, so you could do `\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostdescacronym}{.}` but if you use `\newabbreviation` instead (which does `category=abbreviation`) you'd need to do `\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostdescabbreviation}{.}`.